# Create Custom Module in Zoho CRM through Zoho Rest API

Tags: c#, api, crm, zoho

I have searched through the Zoho CRM API Docs to find a way to create a new Custom Module (Not Records) in CRM by using Zoho API: https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v2/modules-api.html

But I cannot find a way to do that. Can we do it **programatically**? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry using API you cannot create a custom module.

Comment: Yes, that's the same response I got from Zoho team. Anyway, Thanks